# Basic principles of a UDP server with multiple clients

Tags: java, udp, client-server

I'm implementing a FTP program using UDP in Java (TCP is not an option), but I'm having trouble grasping the basics of how it's supposed to work.

As I understand, it's connectionless, so I should just have one server thread running which processes every request by any client.

Where I'm getting confused is during the actual file transfer. If the server is in the middle of a loop sending datagrams containing bits of a requested file to the client, and is waiting for an ACK from the client, but instead of that receives a completely different request from a different client, how am I supposed to handle that?

I know I could jump out of the loop to handle it, but then if the initial expected packet finally arrives, how can I pick up where I left off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A UDP server works similar to a TCP in many respects. The major difference is that you will not receive a acknowledgement that your packets were received. You still have to know which client you are sending to, so use the `DatagramSocket` class. This is the Oracle tutorial for UDP: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/datagrams/index.html. It has a pretty good example in it. The significant part is getting the address and port of the original client, and returning your packets to that client:

```
InetAddress address = packet.getAddress();
int port = packet.getPort();
new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length, address, port);
```

You could start a new thread on the server side for sending the bits every time a client sends a request. The thread would save the return address and port of the client, and die when the file send was done.